# How to keep ms excel from expanding country codes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel containing country codes like "AD". When I try to access this cell in VBA then its value, text or formula returns Andorra. Why the heck is excel doing this? And how can I get the country code? This is driving my crazy ... :-)

EDIT 1:

```
For r = 1 To 32000
    If ws.Cells(r, 1) = "" Then Exit For

    Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, 1)
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, 1).Formula
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, 1).Text
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, 1).Value2

    'Write #i, ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r, 2), ws.Cells(r, 3)
Next r
```

Is returnin all the same "Andorra"

EDIT 2:

You will not beleve what happend. Someone has hidden a column - and I could not see but vba can see ... *shame* But I swear, I have not see this damn hidden col ... sorry. Sometimes its nevertheless more a user fault than a ms fault :-) sorry!

Comment: How does Excel know it's a country code?  Is it an add-on that you have?

Comment: I have no idea. No, it is a plain vanilla excel 2003 ... I have formatted the cells explicitly as text - no success  ...

Comment: What is the VBA code that you are trying to access the cell with look like? (just a snippet)

Comment: I have written AD into a cell, and even put it in a column called "Country Codes" in the off chance that Excel was making a weird leap like that, and I wasn't able to reproduce this.  It's got to be some little setting somewhere lol.

Comment: I would really like to attach my excel ... I have tried various combinations of this props without success either ws.Cells(r, 1).AutoFormat (False) ws.Cells(r, 1).AutoComplete (False) ws.Cells(r, 1).ClearFormats ws.Cells(r, 1).Dirty ... can you add some data in some cells like US, GR, IT, ES and try to save as csv -> I have exactly the same behavior ... arrrggg .. huu ...

Comment: @jonsca: please take a look at "edit 1"

Comment: Try uploading your file to something like rapidshare - maybe when we can get a look me can help. Wacky issue!

Comment: @christian, review the current addin list you have activated. I can only think of two possibilities: 1) you're pointing to the wrong sheet or 2) a external Excel Addin is doing it.

Comment: @christian So you're running the macro on your CSV file by opening it up from another sheet?  I agree with Tiago on this one, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to format your cells as "text". If that isn't working then there is something going on that isn't normal and we'll need more info.

If that doesnt work try reading the cell into VBA and look at the locals windows to see the properties. Also, you might want to they watching a cell in debug and enter a value and see what happens to it to track where the change is coming from.